# mongodb find or aggregate matching an object inside an array of a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out how I can search for all documents which has the same combination of "tags" like the following document.

Meaning that I would like to find all documents which has tags **{brand:"bosh", type:"fridge"} && {type:"freezer", color:"white"}** or any other combination of the tags. Is this possible in  mongo? How can I do that or is there a good explanation somewhere that explains this?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53bd7837156aa38914f55176"),
"user_id" : "53bd1a0d237e7d44120a51d1",
"tags" : [ 
    {
        "brand" : "bosch",
        "type" : "fridge",
        "color" : "black"
    }, 
    {
        "brand" : "electrolux",
        "type" : "freezer",
        "color" : "white"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to match the subdocument and [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator to combine multiple $elemMatch operators:

```js
db.coll.find({
    "tags" : { 
        "$all" : [
            {"$elemMatch" : {"brand": "bosch", "type" : "fridge"}}, 
            {"$elemMatch" : {"type": "freezer", "color": "white"}}
        ]
    }
});
```

This query will find all documents that have subdocuments that have specified values in both fields (i.e. brand && type and type && color).

The following document will **NOT** be matched by the above query (notice that the value of the type fields are reversed):

```js
{
    ...
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "brand" : "bosch",
            "type" : "freezer"
        }, 
        {
            "brand" : "electrolux",
            "type" : "fridge"
        }
    ]
}
```